# clang not found after building llvm

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, clang, llvm

So,This is how I did build LLVM

```
1. Download LLVM from https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project as zip and extract. 

D:/llvm-project/
                |__clang-tools-extra
                |__clang
                |__llvm
                ...
                ...
2. Building using cmake gui
    source : D:/llvm-project/llvm
    Destination : D:/llvm-project/llvm/build
    Optional toolset : host=x64
Click configure
    LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD : X86
Click generate

Now I have D:/llvm-project/llvm/build/llvm.sln 

I opened llvm.sln in visual studio 15 2017
And ALL_BUILD -->Build
```

After building I tried

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\install\bin\clang.exe" –v

But there is no clang

Comment: You need to build `INSTALL` project too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to specify `clang` in the `LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS` CMake variable as described in the [getting started guide](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-the-source-code-and-building-llvm).

Comment: I tried specifying "all". But it gives "perl executables not found" error.

Comment: Eventually I succeeded by specifying "llvm;clang"